# Add a for-loop to VSCode Snippet

Tags: javascript, json, visual-studio-code, code-snippets, vscode-snippets

I successfully created 3 VSCode snippets, I added the 4th one.

```
{
      "for": {
        "prefix": "for",
        "body": "for (i = 0; i < ${1:}.length; i++) {
            console.log(${1:}[i]);
        }"
      }

  }
```

IDE is highlighted as **red**, and I am not able to see it in the snippet list.

[image]

How can I fix that ?

## Goal is to

As I type/select `for` should add this code. Hint: `for` is my snippet prefix.

```
for (i = 0; i < responses.length; i++) {
    console.log(responses[i]);
}
```

Comment: in json, `"\n"` means newline

Comment: or I can specify it as an `array[ ]` of `body` property.

Comment: Javascript `"` strings are not multi-line, do the default `forXXX`snippets not work

Answer (score 2):

I just went through the user defined [snippets](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets) documentation and looks like you have to put the body content in an array. Can you please try this way **:**

```
{
  "for": {
    "prefix": "for",
    "body": ["for (const ${2:element} of ${1:array}) {", "\t$0", "}"]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a working solution, I achived it by doing this:

```
"FOR": {
    "prefix": "for",
    "body": [
        "for (var i = 0; i < ${array}.length; i++) {",
        "\tconsole.log(${array}[i]);",
        "\t$0",
        "}"
    ]
}
```

## Result

As I type

[image]

As I select

[image]